# Strange design in Firefox 12 when only one tab is open

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I have Tab Mix Plus installed and have the tab bar removed when only one tab is open. With Firefox 11, everything was looking alright. Now with Firefox 12 (on Windows Vista) I see the following when only 1 tab is open

[image: 1 tab]

(sorry for the red border; that's just from the snipping tool), while for 2 tabs open I see this:

[image: 2 tabs]

I don't like the design in the first case at all. How can I achieve that I get essentially the **same design for one open tab** as for more open tabs, **but still with the tab bar removed**?

Comment: Sounds like Tabs Mix Plus may be (incorrectly?) removing the background of the "awesome bar" as part of the tab bar. Perhaps post on the [Tabs Mix Plus forums](http://tmp.garyr.net/forum/) about it?

Comment: @Bob: Good suggestion, thanks. The strange thing is that this didn't happen with Firefox 11.

Answer (score 1):

In the preferences dialog, on the "Tabs" tab, click "Always show the tab bar".

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote, I want the tab bar _removed_ when only 1 tab is open. (I tried to make my question a bit clearer.)